# Bundler version and Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

When I am running `bundle` on my local, I am also getting `BUNDLED WITH 1.11.2` inside Gemfile.lock.

Why some teammates who have the same bundler version, when they are doing `bundle`, the `BUNDLED WITH ...` line automatically disappears from the Gemfile.lock ? Is there some option to force it? I also couldn't find when this one change happened and the benefits of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundler does not add that line during `install` with no changes. See `CHANGELOG.md`, added in 1.10.5 (2015-06-24).